# The use of 'the' in scientific terms

Tags: word-choice

I wonder about the use of 'the' for scientific terms, as in the following:

The newton's theory, the multiverse model, the parallel universe model

The question is, whether 'the' is always needed in the above situations. For example, whether 'the' is needed without the term being aforementioned, or in the title of a paper or book.

Comment: It's context dependent. Nothing to do with science *per se*.

Comment: how how how how how

Comment: Do some research. And let us know what you found, too. Good Luck.

Comment: Show me one instance where it says "the" Newton's theory.

Comment: @Justin 'the' newton's theory is perhaps wrong. but what about other scientific terms in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing here which is unique to scientific models or theories. With one exception, the examples you have provided are simply compound nouns which require the definite article when they are placed in a position in a sentence which requires an article.

The exception is "The Newton's theory" - which is plain wrong. I'm not sure where you read this. Newton is the name of a man, and you do not apply articles to people's names. You would simply say "Newton's theory"; "The theory of Newton", or, if you wanted something close to your own quote, "The man's theory" (where the man was Newton).

Example requiring an article:

- I first read about the multiverse theory when I was 15.

Example not requiring an article:

- Multiverse-theory adherents tend to have an interest in science.

There's nothing unique in this usage which is applied especially to scientific concepts. You could substitute any other similar compound nouns in their place.

Comment: great answer. so if i write a paper or book entitled: 'multiverse theory and its variations', the title should b changed to 'the multiverse theory and its variations'?

Comment: @feynman, it depends if there's only one multiverse theory or several. There are cases where we leave off the article like "decision theory" or "game theory" because we're actually talking about a whole class of theories rather than a single theory.